# Backwards Compatibility issue with Visual studio express 2012 and 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012

I developed an MVC4 Web application in Microsoft Visual Studio Express 2012 for Web. I brought a copy of the solution into my computer in college which has Microsoft Visual Studio 2010. However when I try to open it I am given the following error:

> This project is incompatible with the current version of Visual Studio.

Is there any way I can somehow port the project so that I can open it in this version of Visual Studio??

Comment: You might need to install Visual Studio SP1 and ASP.NET MVC 4 http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30683

Comment: VS2010 and VS2012 use different project file formats.  They are incompatible.